# Parsing on server versus parsing on localhost

Tags: parsing

Here is my code:

```
if (amount != -1)
    returnJson.Add("<p style=\"color: black;\">" + double.Parse(res_q.Replace(",", ".")) * amount + " " + res_i + "</p>");
else
    returnJson.Add("<p style=\"color: black;\">" + res_q + " " + " ") + res_i + "</p>");
```

And no matter if the execution of the program goes to if or the else, if res_q="1,5", this returns 15 on server, and 1.5 locally.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the comma.

I want to apply globalization in my program. Using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture was the answer I needed. Or simple replcing the comma with dot.